# firestore REST order by 2 fields ( composite query )

Tags: firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore, composite-index

the firestore REST documentation doesn't mention info about compound queries
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/list

1. How can I order by 2 fields when querying a list of documents ? ( for example, I want the student documents to be ordered by the student school ID then by the student average score )
2. do I need to manually generate the composite index ( the sdks provide you with a url to generate the required composite index )?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

somehow I missed it in the docs, here is the syntax for composite queries, simply separate the fields by a comma

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/listDocuments

cities?orderBy=likeCount, likeAverage